# Authenticity of narration on Prophet's Nur

Tags: hadith

Need authenticity of this narration:

> “When Adam (peace be upon him) was being created, the nur of Prophet
> Muhammad (may Allah bless him and grant him peace) was placed on
> Adam’s (peace be upon him) forehead and Adam saw the Prophet Muhammad
> (may Allah bless him and grant him peace). Adam (may Allah bless him
> and grant him peace) asked, ‘Who is he?’ Allah Most High replied, ‘He
> is the last Prophet and will be the chief of your children’ ”
>
> [Ibn al-Jawzi, Al Wafa, chapter on ‘Birth of the Prophet]

Comment: "Chapter on "Birth of the Prophet" is rather vague, at least this narrative is not in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this the hadith

"عن كعب الأحبار قال: لما أراد الله تعالى أن يخلق محمداً صلى الله عليه وسلم أمر جبريل عليه السلام أن يأتيه فأتاه بالقبضة البيضاء التي هي موضع قبر رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، فعجنت بماء التَّسْنيم، ثم غمست في أنهار الجنة، وطيف بها في السموات والأرض، فعرفت الملائكة محمداً وفَضْله قبل أن تعرف آدم، ثم كان نور محمد صلى الله عليه وسلم يُرى في غُرَّة جبهة آدم. وقيل له: يا آدم هذا سيد ولدك من الأنبياء والمرسلين.

فلما حملت حواء بشيت انتقل عن آدم إلى حواء، وكانت تلد في كل بطن ولدين إلا شيتاً، فإنها ولدته وحده، كرامة لمحمد صلى الله عليه وسلم. ثم لم يزل ينتقل من طاهر إلى طاهر إلى أن ولد صلى الله عليه وسلم"

From Ka'ab al-Ahbar: "When Allah ta'ala want to create Prophet Muhammad s.a.w., He ordered Jibril a.s. to bring a handful of white soil which is the soil where the Prophet s.a.w. will be buried later. Then the soil is mixed with Tasniim water (heavent water) and then dipped into the rivers of heaven. After that, he's taken around the skies and the earth. The angels also recognized the Prophet s.a.w. and his superiority/virtue before they recognized Prophet Adam a.s. When the Nur of the Prophet s.a.w. is seen on the forehead of Prophet Adam a.s., it was said to him: "O Adam, this is the sayyid (chief) of your descendants from the anbiya 'and the mursalin.
When Eve was pregnant with the Prophet Syits, Nur Muhammad moved to Eve. Eve who usually gives birth to twins every time she is pregnant, but in this pregnancy she only gave birth to one child, namely the Prophet Syits because of the glory of the Prophet s.a.w. So Nur Muhammad always shifted from one holy person to another holy person until he was the one who's born"

(Translated by google translate and me with a little revision so expect mistakes)

The hadith is not strong. Imam as-Suyuthy in al-Haawi fil Fatwa juz 1 p. 325 said "the hadith does not have a sanad that can be relied on" In the book Kasyful Khofa” it's indicated that the hadith was narrated by Abdurrozzaq, but if you do research, the hadith is not found in the books compiled by Abdurrozzaq, either in his Mushonnaf, al-Jaami', or Tafsir.

Instead the hadith contradict other hadith other hadith such as:

The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Angels were created from light, jinns were created from a smokeless flame of fire, and 'Adam was created from that which you have been told (i.e., sounding clay like the clay of pottery)."

[Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1846)

even contradict the Qur'an

"Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “I am only a man like you, ˹but˺ it has been revealed to me that your God is only One God. So whoever hopes for the meeting with their Lord, let them do good deeds and associate none in the worship of their Lord."
Al kahfi 110

This is copied from [this](https://ilmuislam2011.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/apakah-rosululullah-diciptakan-dari-cahaya-nur-benarkah-nur-muhammad-berpindah-pindah-dari-seorang-yang-suci-kepada-orang-suci-yang-lain/) with a little translation revision. Wallahu a'lam

Comment: I already got an answer. There is actually a difference of opinion regarding this narration.

Comment: What the link mistakenly addresses is not the status of these particular ahadith but the one allegedly from Jabir that the Prophet ﷺ was created from the light of Allah ﷻ and not from the soil of Earth. I'm Malay btw.